# Hidden input not being read from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik

I have a hidden input, used to store a number used by a stored procedure.  I have a button that when clicked, updates the input's value.

```
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
.... other stuff ....

    <input type="hidden" id="NumberOfResults" runat="server" />
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>

var numOfResults = RadAjaxPanel1.FindControl("NumberOfResults") as HtmlInputHidden;
numOfResults.Value = "250";
```

When I look at the input using Firebug, the value is 250, as it should be.

The problem: The next time I call the input, the value isn't 250, it's the previous value:

```
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        var resultsInput = (HtmlInputHidden)RadAjaxPanel1.FindControl("NumberOfResults");
        int? numberOfResults = Convert.ToInt32(resultsInput.Value);            
        //This ^ should be 250

        long? routeID = Convert.ToInt64(RouteID.Value);

        RadGrid1.DataSource = GetDataTable(customerID, null, plantID, numberOfResults, routeID);
    }
```

How can I get the `NeedDataSource` event to see the new value?

Note: The value is initially set in the `Page_Load` event:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        //Initial values for filtering
        NumberOfResults.Value = Convert.ToString(int.MaxValue);
    }
```

Comment: Page_Load is going to fire on every post back, you should check for IsPostBack and not set NumberOfResults.Value

Comment: That solved it!  If you want to post an answer I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page_Load is going to fire on every post back, you should check for IsPostBack and not set NumberOfResults.Value